# PhoneGap build command not working after updating to Yosemite

Tags: cordova, ios8, xcode6, osx-yosemite

I am developing an application in PhoneGap. Before updating my iMac to OSX Yosemite the phonegap was working perfectly the build commands and all that. But after updating to OSX Yosemite, whenever I run the build command I get this error:

```
phonegap build ios
[phonegap] detecting iOS SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling iOS...
Unknown option: n
Usage: head [-options] <url>...
    -m <method>   use method for the request (default is 'HEAD')
    -f            make request even if head believes method is illegal
    -b <base>     Use the specified URL as base
    -t <timeout>  Set timeout value
    -i <time>     Set the If-Modified-Since header on the request
    -c <conttype> use this content-type for POST, PUT, CHECKIN
    -a            Use text mode for content I/O
    -p <proxyurl> use this as a proxy
    -P            don't load proxy settings from environment
    -H <header>   send this HTTP header (you can specify several)

    -u            Display method and URL before any response
    -U            Display request headers (implies -u)
    -s            Display response status code
    -S            Display response status chain
    -e            Display response headers
    -d            Do not display content
    -o <format>   Process HTML content in various ways

    -v            Show program version
    -h            Print this message

    -x            Extra debugging output
Cordova can only run in Xcode version 4.6 or greater.
{ [Error: /Volumes/Macintosh HD 2/Aleem Data/Projects On Mac/IPhone Application Projects/Growing Feet/New Version Test/GrowingFeet/growingfeet/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2] code: 2 }
   [error] /Volumes/Macintosh HD 2/Aleem Data/Projects On Mac/IPhone Application Projects/Growing Feet/New Version Test/GrowingFeet/growingfeet/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
```

I am using Xcode 6.1 and OSX Yosemite and I have updated my version to the latest version of Phonegap which is: **3.6.0-0.21.19** but still it gives the same error.